# environments, sys.frame() and sys.nframe in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

Hy!
I'm playing around with environments in R.
Here is a minimal example:

```
test_function <- function() {
 list2env(list(test = 5), envir = sys.frame(sys.nframe()))
  test_function2()
}

test_function2 <- function() {
  #access variable test here
}
```

Part 2

```
test_function <- function() {
  print(sys.nframe())
  x <- 5
 list2env(list(test = x), envir = sys.frame(sys.nframe()))
  test_function2()
}

test_function2 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  print(sys.nframe())
  x <- envir$test
  if (x<5) {
    test_function3()
  } else{
    test_function2()
  }

}
test_function3 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  
}
```

In the second call of test_function2() I can not access test.

Can anyone tell me how to access the variable test inside test_function2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using `test_function` from question we retrieve `test` from the parent frame:

```
test_function2 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
    envir$test
}

test_function()
## [1] 5
```

### Part 2

`envir` needs to be passed down. That is why it was made an argument in the first part.  We have modified the example to remove the infinite recursion.

```
test_function <- function(x) {
  list2env(list(test = x), environment())
  test_function2(z = 5)
}

test_function2 <- function(z, envir = parent.frame()) {
  x <- envir$test
  if (x<z) test_function3(envir) else Recall(z+1, envir)
}

test_function3 <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  envir$test
}

trace(test_function)
trace(test_function2)
trace(test_function3)

test_function(4)
## trace: test_function(4)
## trace: test_function2
## trace: test_function3
## [1] 4

test_function(5)
## trace: test_function(5)
## trace: test_function2
## trace: test_function2
## trace: test_function3
## [1] 5
```

Comment: And how is the method if I have many functions and the parent.frame() isn't the same all the time? My goal is to list variables to environments and access them from every "sub"-function.

Comment: `test_function2` should work with any caller that contains `test`.  `ls(envir)` will list the variable names in the parent.

Comment: I have added my problem in the main question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: with the infinite incursion I wanted to reach that i call test_function2 a second time. Because then the parent.frame() is the environment of test_funtion2. Or am I wrong?

Comment: OK. I have modified it so that test_function2 calls itself once.  The key point is that by passing `envir` down through an argument we can access `test` in `test_function` even from functions invoked deep within the call tree.